# Apex: Getting namespace prefix

Tags: apex, managed-package, namespace

We have a scenario where we need to make assignments to fields using the method `put(String, Object)`

Ref:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_put

Once in a managed package the assignment:

```
String oldDesc = (String)acc.put('Custom_Field__c', 'some value');
```

will fail, because the packaged field will have a namespace prefix. So if it's been packaged as

```
`mypackage`
```

, the correct put() call would be:

```
String oldDesc = (String)acc.put('mypackage__Custom_Field__c', 'some value');
```

How can I avoid hard coding a package namespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can suggest getting the namespace from the current class name..

```
public String getNamespacePrefix() {
    String namespacePrefix;
    String[] classNameParts = String.valueOf(<Enter className>.class).split('\\.', 2);
    if(classNameParts.size() > 1) {
        Type classType = Type.forName(classNameParts[0], classNameParts[1]);
        if(classType == <Enter className>.class) {
            namespacePrefix = classNameParts[0];
        } else {
            namespacePrefix = '';
        }
    } else {
        //If there is only one part, the class has no namespace
        namespacePrefix = '';
    }
    return namespacePrefix; 
}
```

Comment: If you're going to call this method frequently, it might be worth making it static, putting it in a utility class, and having it cache the result for subsequent calls.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This is just an example. If you are going to use this, do as Mr.DOS has suggested.

Comment: @Mr.DOS how would you cache it?

Comment: What happens if there are two classes called "My.class"? It seems like there's no way for an apex file to be able to access information about itself.

Comment: @bananka If I'm going to put the method in a utility class anyway, I'd add a static field to that class (`private static String namespacePrefix = null;`). At the top of the `getNamespacePrefix()` method, I'd check to see if that field was non-null, and if so, I'd return it. Otherwise, I'd go through the process of determining the namespace prefix, but right before `return`ing, I'd set the value of the static field.

Comment: @Mr.DOS but wouldn't null be returned on the next call in any case?..

Comment: @bananka I've written an [example](https://gist.github.com/MrDOS/e0d65a61bd72a75df404) of this pattern. Hopefully this will clear up what I'm suggesting.

Comment: @Mr.DOS thanks for the sample. This cache is only alive until the page is closed and the apex transaction ends, isn't it? I guess it could be more useful in java or c#.

Comment: That's right. The “calculation” will be performed the first time it is requested within the scope of a page load. But in this case, I don't think it's a *huge* overhead. If it were really bad, you could store the result of the calculation in a [hierarchical custom setting](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_about.htm), then construct a two-level caching solution which retrieves the value of the custom setting into a static field. (I've never run into a situation which warranted that, but YMMV.)

Comment: @navD87 What if there are 2 managed packages and they are having the same class name. For example Utils.class. Will it work in that case too?

Comment: Doesn't work in client's org with installed package, the code gives Error: Invalid type: [classFromMyPackage]

Answer (score 5):

If the logic is in a class known to not be an inner class then the logic can be simpler:

```
public class Utils {
    // Return the namespace prefix or an empty string if there isn't one
    public static String namespacePrefix {
        get {
            if (namespacePrefix == null) {
                String[] parts = String.valueOf(Utils.class).split('\\.', 2);
                namespacePrefix = parts.size() == 2 ? parts[0] : '';
            }
            return namespacePrefix;
        }
        private set;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I run it in execute anonymous and get Error: Invalid type: [classFromMyPackage]

Comment: @AndriiMuzychuk As that type name isn't part of the code I posted, that error is not evidence that the posted code does not work.

Answer (score 4):

Can you not try like this without doing any extra efforts? If you know any custom field or custom object of your managed package then the following solution should work.

**If you have a custom object with *Custom_Object__c* API Name**

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsr = Custom_Object__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
String namespacePrefix = dsr.getName().remove(dsr.getLocalName());
```

**If you have a custom field with *Custom_Field__c* API Name**

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Account.sObjectType.fields.Custom_Field__c.getDescribe();
String namespacePrefix = dfr.getName().remove(dfr.getLocalName());
```

I think this way you don't need to do any query on Apex class. Doing a query or using an apex class may lead you in a wrong path as there could be 2 managed packages with the same class name but there won't be a problem with 2 fields with the same API name since it will pick the managed package field.

Comment: Perfect solution!